# C# xml documentation, do i need to escape quotes, and <, > in the <code> section?

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

C# xml documentation, do i need to escape special XML characters, like: quotes, < >  in the

> < code>

section?

Comment: AFAIR you can escape <> for generic types with []

Comment: I usually wrap the Contents of a code tag in Cdata.. Then no escaping is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that we do need to escape the usual XML characters: <, >, but " are ok either way .